# Editing a form in a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a theme on Envato but it seems the team cannot (or don't want) help me.

On each propertypage, we have a button calling a form in a modal box.
I've added some fields by myself but I don't know how to send the new arrays by mail.

So, the form works this way:

A file called form.php contains:

```
<div class="mkdf-property-enquiry-holder">
    <div class="mkdf-property-enquiry-inner">
        <a class="mkdf-property-enquiry-close">
            <?php echo zuhaus_mikado_icon_collections()->renderIcon( 'icon_close_alt', 'font_elegant' );?>
        </a>
        <form class="mkdf-property-enquiry-form mkdf-style-form" method="POST">

            <label class="formx"><?php echo get_the_title();?></label>//ADDED FIELD
            <label class="formx"><?php echo get_the_ID();?></label>//ADDED FIELD
            <label><?php esc_html_e('Full Name', 'mkdf-real-estate'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="enquiry-name" id="enquiry-name" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Your Full Name', 'mkdf-real-estate' );?>" required pattern=".{6,}">
            <label><?php esc_html_e('E-mail Address', 'mkdf-real-estate'); ?></label>
            <input type="email" name="enquiry-email" id="enquiry-email" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Your E-mail Address', 'mkdf-real-estate' );?>" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
            <label><?php esc_html_e('GSM / TEL'); ?></label>
            <input type="phone" name="enquiry-phone" id="enquiry-phone" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Téléphone / GSM', 'mkdf-real-estate' );?>" required>
            <label><?php esc_html_e('Your Message', 'mkdf-real-estate'); ?></label>
            <textarea name="enquiry-message" id="enquiry-message" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Your Message', 'mkdf-real-estate' );?>" required></textarea>

            <?php echo zuhaus_mikado_get_button_html(array(
                'text' => esc_html__('Send Your Message', 'mkdf-real-estate'),
                'html_type' => 'button',
                'type' => 'solid',
                'custom_class' => 'mkdf-property-single-enquiry-submit'
            )); ?>

            <input type="hidden" id="property-item-id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php wp_nonce_field('mkdf_re_validate_property_item_enquiry', 'mkdf_re_nonce_property_item_enquiry'); ?>
        </form>
        <div class="mkdf-property-enquiry-response"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, there's a file called function-helper which contains that:

```
 //Get post id from request
                    $post_id = $email_data['itemId'];
                    //Get email address
                    $contact_user = mkdf_re_get_property_contact_user($post_id);
                    $mail_to = $contact_user->user_email;
                    $headers = array(
                        'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>',
                        'Reply-To: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>',
                    );


                    $additional_emails = array();

                    $additional_emails[] = $mail_to;
                    $headers[] = 'Bcc: ' . implode(',', $additional_emails);

           $messageTemplate = esc_html__('Bien', 'mkdf-real-estate'). ': ' . XXXXXXX . "\r\n";
           $messageTemplate .= esc_html__('ID du Bien', 'mkdf-real-estate'). ': ' XXXXXXX "\r\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__('De', 'mkdf-real-estate'). ': ' . $name . "\r\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__('Message', 'mkdf-real-estate') . ': ' . $message . "\r\n\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Message envoyé par le site', 'mkdf-real-estate' ) . ' ' . get_bloginfo('name') . ' - ' . esc_url( home_url('/') );
```

My question is, how to add the missing fields in the function-helper.php?
The missing fields are written XXXXXXX.

Here's a link to see the modal box: http://www.iaci.be/property/villa/#

Comment: You have to find where did you get `$name` and `$message` value. May be there is another file to accept the form value with variable. Example, function.php file in the plugin.

Comment: After many attempts and searches, this theme needs 4 files to send an e-mail. Well, it's weird but i managed to customize it. Thanks.

Comment: Alright. Is it work now?